# URL path which includes a Express JS request parameter having issues downloading, versus a clean string of the same text

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, window.open

I have an app which uses Express.js to serve its static pages and also for some endpoints which handle zipping/saving files that the user can then download.

Within my regular JS application, I call the server to ask for a zip archive, and await the response synchronously:

```
var params = {
    "save_id": saveID // "test"
}

var paramsString = jQuery.param(params)

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhttp.open("POST", "finaliseSave?" + paramsString, false);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send();

var archivePath = xhttp.response
```

I then download the file:

```
window.open(archivePath)
```

On the server side, this looks like this:

```
app.post("/finaliseSave", function(request, response) {
    var saveID = request.query["save_id"] // "test"

    //... prepare the file for the user to download ...

    //Download path to give to the user
    var downloadPath = "./tmp/" + saveID + ".zip" // "./tmp/test.zip"

    console.log(downloadPath) // "./tmp/test.zip"

    //Return the download path
    response.end(downloadPath);
})
```

I can go to the file in my `/public/tmp/` directory and see that the file size is 1.1mb - I can even copy it to my downloads folder, unzip it and get at the contents.

However, that file which was downloaded with the `window.open()` line is much smaller - 808kb - and when I attempt to unzip it, I get an error of "Unable to expand (No such file or directory)".

So, if I replace this line on my server:

```
var downloadPath = "./tmp/" + saveID + ".zip" // "./tmp/test.zip"
```

with this:

```
var downloadPath = "./tmp/" + "test" + ".zip" // "./tmp/test.zip"
```

(I can also add this under another variable name, then console.log an equality check between that and the original downloadPath, and it tells me they're equal.)

And then I return this `downloadPath`, and call `window.open()`, it downloads the file correctly, and unzips correctly.

It seems there *is* some difference between these two:

```
var saveID = request.query["save_id"] // "test"
var saveID = "test" // "test"
```

Somehow this affects the downloading of the file, and I'm not sure why.